# What is the reason of initializing an instance of a Class Form inside the Main in Windows Form Projects?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, oop, model-view-controller

I've created a kind of test project that its name is : `WinFormsMVC`.
I've used MVC architecture in this project, so that I placed the Class `Program.cs` inside the folder `Controllers`, then created a Class inside the folder `Models` and named it : `UserInfo`, this is my UserInfo.cs :

```
namespace WinFormsMVC.Models
{
    public class UserInfo
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then I created the folder `Views` and then created a Windows Form Application inside it and named it : `FirstForm`.
Now I have a project with MVC architecture.

I've defined UserInfo as property in `FirstForm` code behind.
At the first line of the Class below, I've defined it :

```
 public partial class FirstForm : Form
    {
        public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
        public FirstForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void txtFName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserInfo.Name = txtFName.Text;
        }

        private void txtLName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserInfo.Family = txtLName.Text;
        }

        private void txtEmail_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserInfo.Email = txtEmail.Text;
        }
    }
```

Now inside the `Program.cs`, when I want to run the project, I have to set `info` to `f1.UserInfo`.
I want to know why the reason of setting it to `f1.UserInfo`? Because I've setted the information in Class `FirstForm.cs`, for example, inside the `FirstForm.cs` I have:

```
private void txtLName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserInfo.Family = txtLName.Text;
     }
```

So why do I have to write : `f1.UserInfo=info;` while I've alredy done it in Class `FirstForm`??
This is my Class Main :

```
 static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            UserInfo info = new UserInfo();

            var f1 = new FirstForm();
            f1.UserInfo = info;
            f1.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Because I've setted the information in Class FirstForm.cs

No, you haven't all you've done is defined a property - you haven't set it to anything. If you want to set it to an instance, you can do that in the constructor:

```
public UserInfo UserInfo { get; set; }
public FirstForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserInfo = new UserInfo();
}
```